# Finding the boundary of a subset of $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $\mathbb{Q}=\{q_1, q_2,...\}$ and $S=\bigcup_{k\in\mathbb{N}}{N_{1/2^k}}{(q_k)}$ (where $N_{1/2^k}(q_k)$ is the open neighborhood around $q_k$)  be a subset of $\mathbb{R}$.

The questions asks to find boundary of $S$.

I know that the boundary of a set is the intersection of its closure and the closure of its compliment. Since we are examining shrinking neighborhoods around the elements in $\mathbb{Q}$, and since $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$, is the boundary of $S$ just $\mathbb{R}$ itself? If this isn't correct, could someone point me in the right direction? Many thanks.

Comment: Well, can $q_1$ lie on the boundary of $S$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer.** $\,\partial S=\mathbb R\smallsetminus S$.

By definition, $\partial S=\overline{S}\cap\overline{\mathbb R\smallsetminus S}$,
and $\mathbb R\smallsetminus S$ is closen, then  $\partial S=\overline{S}\cap{\mathbb R\smallsetminus S}$. It suffices to show that 
$$
x\in\mathbb R\smallsetminus S\quad\Longrightarrow\quad x\in\overline{S}.
$$
But is $x\not\in S$, then $x$ is irrational, and it can be approximated by rationals, and hence $x$ is a limit point of $S$, i.e., $x\in\overline{S}$.

Comment: Put in less problem-specific terms, the boundary is always the closure minus the interior. In this case the set is open, so you have the closure minus the set itself. Also in this case the set is dense, so you have the whole space minus the set itself.